# Get filename of downloadable binary from php url without actually downloading the file

Tags: javascript, php, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm doing some webscraping with Selenium in Python and I have a link on a page that points to, e.g.

```
<a href="/zip.php?zipid=103">Click Here To Download</a>
```

Now, of course, if I click on it, my browser will immediately start downloading the file, e.g. `myinterestingarchive.zip`

What I'm wondering is if I can inject some JavaScript, say, that will tell me the filename `myinterestingarchive.zip` WITHOUT my clicking the link, because I'd like to record the filename in my program's log, and it's nowhere in the source or OuterHTML, just that php url.

Comment: There's no filename "myinterestingarchive.zip" in that URL, only the id of it, which is recognized at the server-side as "myinterestingarchive.zip". You could try to get the filename with a head-type AJAX call ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it support `HEAD` request that will only download http headers you can do

```
import requests

......
# set the request with selenium cookies
cookies = {c['name']: c['value'] for c in driver.get_cookies()}
response = requests.head('http://....../zip.php?zipid=103', cookies=cookies )
print(response.headers['Content-Disposition'])
# attachment; filename=zip/myinterestingarchive.zip
```

And yes you can do this with injected JavaScript but it more simple using `requests`

Comment: The reason I was using Selenium is that the site requires log-in and I couldn't figure out how the cookies worked, but this seems like the perfect time to finally try out `requestium`.

Comment: I added code how to use selenium cookies in `requests`